# Creating constraintset from layout with merge

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I want to do a `Changebounds()` animation from one constraintSet to another.

Normally I do this by creating two constraint sets:

```
private val originalState = ConstraintSet().apply {
    clone(context, R.layout.layout_meta_syntactic)
}

private val expandedState = ConstraintSet().apply {
    clone(context, R.layout.layout_meta_syntactic)
    // Change some constraints
    connect(
        R.id.button, ConstraintSet.END,
        R.id.foo_text, ConstraintSet.START
    )
}
```

And animate back and forth with:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(id_of_my_component_in_fragment, transition)
originalState.applyTo(id_of_my_component_in_fragment)
```

But now I'm stuck with a `<merge>` tag in the layout I want to clone from. The merge layout is the base for a compound component which extends ConstraintLayout.

Compound component:

```
class MyCompoundView : ConstraintLayout {

// Omissions
inflate(context, R.layout.layout_meta_syntactic, this)
```

inflating:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    // Views
```

When trying to clone the layout into a constraint set programatically I get:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
```

How do I go about creating constraint sets from such a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create another (dummy) layout file with `ConstraintLayout` root that holds your layout reference with `include` tag.
2. Clone layout params from new instance of your custom view:  `ConstraintSet.clone(context, MyCompoundView(context))`.

`ConstraintSet.clone(context, layoutRes)` is actually pretty crude under the hood ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/sherpa/+/studio-3.0/constraintlayout/src/main/java/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.java#620)), it essentially inflates new `ConstraintLayout` from provided layout file including all child views before resolving their layout params to build `ConstraintSet`.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that crudeness when debugging, breakpoints triggering for every clone(layoutId). But is there a better way to do it though? Do I get around it by cloning an inflated constraint layout?

Comment: @Adam yes, if You already have an instance of inflated `ConstraintLayout` it builds the set by iterating over children and their layout params.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to clone the compound component which is a ConstraintLayout

```
class MyCompoundView : ConstraintLayout {

    // make sure to clone after inflating the layout to the component

    originalState = ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(this@MyCompoundView)
    }

    expandedState = ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(this@MyCompoundView)
        // Change some constraints
         connect(
             R.id.button, ConstraintSet.END,
             R.id.foo_text, ConstraintSet.START
        )
    }
}
```